# how do I change a Ultra High voltage AC currents frequency?

Tags: ac, frequency, vfd

I am currently making a theoretical tabletop particle accelerator. and i need the materials in the accelorator to be resonating together at a set frequency (Whcih I can change to test speicific theories)
The key is High voltage. ---
The secondary requirement is AC current ---
The third is the frequency

I can step up household AC via a transformer up to 300KV AC
Since transformers are tuned typically at a set frequency I cant change the frequency before I step up the voltage , I have to do it afterwards
NOTE: the frequency needs to be changeable so that the different ferromagnetic/parametric and diamagnetic materials i am using have their own fundamental harmonic frequencies and what i am attempting to do is match 2 different materials fundamental frequencies be picking a higher frequency that resonates with both materials used.

Ok with that all explained - How do I change a Ultra High Voltage AC's frequency ...

Other materials lets say one is 15hz and the other is 20hz would resonate both at AC frequency 60hz...

Im testing a lot of materials . One of the most common frequency for a few materials is 85-90 Hz . Some higher frequencies are 300-340hz, lowest would be 10hz

Comment: How much power/current do you need to deliver to your sample?

Comment: I am interested to see the answer to this question. However I'm nearly certain that you are wrong, and it will be easier to generate  a different frequency in a low voltage regime, and step it up with a different transformer for different frequencies, or with some kind of adjustable tuning circuit to make a single transformer useful over a wider frequency range.

Comment: I need the current/ampere/power to be low so that it doesn't heat up - In fact the current isn't the important factor and the higher it is the more heating, and eddys will occur.

Comment: Actually good point. Yes I wonder if their are transformers that can handle 10-350 hz changes... otherwise having a number of transformers designed - like you siad - have the input wall low voltage modified, first, into the frequency required - then have the appropriate transformer connect to said power and step it up... My dilemma here is I first need to test certain frequencies to see which frequencies harmonise with the materials. Theoretically i know the frequency of the materials when 100% pure but to actually get those pure materials is like buying gold... kind costly.

Comment: Or somehow make a more sensitive test so that you can find the resonance with, say, a 50 V signal instead of 300 kV.

Comment: good idea - I wonder still if their is something out there that can change a ultra high voltage AC frequency - Still though one Frequency modulation device/method for a single High Voltage AC transformer if it exists - would be ideal

Comment: There's nothing out there that can change the frequency of a 300kV sine wave that would fit with the concept of a tabletop device.  I suspect the easiest way to do it would be to step it down with a transformer, rectify it, generate a sine wave with a variable frequency inverter and then step it back up with a transformer designed to operate over the total frequency range.  So in your case you already have the lower voltage, start there then step it up.

Comment: WHY do you think you "cant change the frequency before I step up the voltage"?  In fact, that is the NORMAL way of doing this. Old CRT television and computer monitors all used "flyback transformers" to generate high-frequency high-voltage (typically around 15-20KHz.  Note that all Tesla coils, etc. are high-frequency. It is completely impractical to do this down at utility power mains frequencies (50-60Hz).  The basic assumptions of your question seem incorrect and unsupportable.

Comment: SO basically from what I have seen and heard, which thank you all, its not possible with current tech to change the frequency at high voltages. First change the frequency at low and step up? Oh the unsupportable aspect I agree - hence the research but I can say that particle acceleration is a diverse field :) Again though I still leave it open to anyone who might have a solution on how to modify high voltage AC at the source and change the frequency. - or on the low end side ->Does anyone know of broad range transformer that can handle a broad range of frequencies like u suggested?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. All tube audio amplifiers work just fine in the 20Hz - 20kHz range. A little design effort to avoid dielectric breakdowns, sectional design of coils with teflon bobbin, epoxy molding, immersion into transformer oil, or whatever people do. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mechanically drive a DC generator with a motor. 
Excite the DC generator with your 10-350 hz AC. 
Send the output through a variac to your HV transformer. 
Vary your frequency with your exciter. 
Vary your HV with a variac between the generator output and your HV transformer. 
Generator output frequency should be independent of mechanical speed. 
Be careful as insulators breakdown with higher voltages and higher frequencies can conduct through capacities.

Comment: I was thinking the insulation is a big issue , which of these do you think (or other suggestions) would be best for limiting breakdown? -section bobbins, silicone potting, heatshrink sleeving, nylon mounting bolts and or standoffs ? This seems like a great solution though

Comment: Also - This is probably a armature question. But if you use a AC current to excite a DC generator - will the output from the DC Generator therefore become AC? I would assume so since I will be sending the voltage into a transformer

Comment: HV transformer is where insulation breakdown could be a problem. I would suggest a Tesla coil secondary. As for DC output, a DC generator output polarity is set by its excitation. Varying excitation should change the output. Higher frequencies than designed, will have lower efficiencies and may heat up more depending on load and time.

Comment: Corona Dope for all sharp edges / connections, and tesla or x-ray wire/cable. Be careful of dielectric failure, radiation, high speed particles, ozone, resonant frequencies at high "Q"s can produce extremely high voltages well beyond turn ratios. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_cable

Comment: So I understand i need AC current with high volatge for my experiment... If I excite the DC generator with AC at specific Frequencies then doesnt the DC still stay DC and the frequency wouldnt change? I just want to understand the process here and what the resulting volage Frequency will be. To be honest I personally dont care if its AC or DC as long as the current has the frequencies i need.

Comment: DC does not have a frequency, so it's probably AC you want or an AC component atop DC. A simpler way may be to use a computer sound card to create the frequency you want and a power amplifier to drive the HV transformer.